# WSL2 cannot connect to the Internet when Sangfor aTrust is running

Tags: networking, wireshark, wsl2, network-protocols

I am using WSL2 on Windows 11 22H2 22624.1470. Ubuntu 22.04.6 LTS installed on WSL2. When I run a program called aTrust, which is developed by a corporation called Sangfor, my WSL2 cannot connect to the Internet or any IP addresses including even the gateway `172.17.160.1`. I tried to figure out what caused the problem. I searched everywhere but didn't find anything useful about Sangfor aTrust and WSL2. By using WireShark, I found all ICMP Protocals had `No Respond Found` Warning, regardless of what IP address I ping. Moreover, when I use `traceroute 172.17.160.1`, I could only get:

```
traceroute to 172.17.160.1 (172.17.160.1), 64 hops max
  1   *  *  *
  2   *  *  *
  3   *  *  *
  4   *  * ^C
```

Below is the file `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.17.160.1
```

I know I can change the nameserver into 1.1.1.1 or 9.9.9.9, etc, but I cannot connect to any of the addresses above in WSL2.

When I quit the aTrust program, everything will be OK, but I don't want to quit it frequently as I need to use it to keep connected to my University network to do my work.
I hope someone can help me solve the problem. I am not quite good at using Linux as I just began to learn how to use Linux, that's why I am using WSL instead of a computer running Ubuntu. I'm not familiar with Internet protocals, but just followed instructions on the Internet, trying to find what's wrong.

I added a rule in WindowsFirewall, which allows all protocals & ports from IP addresses from `172.17.160.2` to `172.17.160.254` to access all local addresses & ports (I' afraid it is risky), but it could only make `172.17.160.1` accessible, but all DNS cannot be solved. Any IP addresses including 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8 cannot be accessed either. I think there must be something else went wrong.

Surprisingly, when I use Wireshark to capture WLAN instead of vEthernet(WSL), DNS solutions of the website I pinged inside WSL is just okay and I could see an IP address of the host returned to my Windows system.

I have also tried to traceroute an IP address after I edited the Firewall:

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 64 hops max
  1   172.17.160.1  0.358ms  0.202ms  0.205ms
  2   *  *  *
  3   *  *  *
  4   *  *  *
  5   * ^C
```

It worked, but still useless.

Yes, I can just end the aTrust program to make everything okay, but I am really tired of turing it on to log in and turing it off to use WSL2. I hope someone can help me find a solution.

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting I found:

> Some users have reported issues with specific firewall applications blocking internet access in WSL. The firewalls reported are:
>
> Kaspersky
>
> AVG
>
> Avast
>
> Symantec Endpoint Protection
>
> In some cases turning off the firewall allows for access. In some cases simply having the firewall installed looks to block access.

Well, perhaps Sangfor aTrust will be added to the list. Below I will introduce what I've found it had done to my computer as you might be unfamiliar with the program. It is a bad program, but I have to use it.

I've checked the Windows Settings and found No VPNs or Proxies are created by aTrust. However, a virtual network is created and cannot be termitated as it will recover in no time when I block it by something like a Service or background process I've not found. The network has no Internet access but made my computer 2.0.0.1 (an IP address in France):

```
C:\>tracert 2.0.0.1

通过最多 30 个跃点跟踪
到 DESKTOP-94DT041 [2.0.0.1] 的路由:

  1    <1 毫秒   <1 毫秒   <1 毫秒 myDESKTOP [2.0.0.1]

跟踪完成。
```

Using cmd.exe (In Chinese Simplified)

And it created a new virtual network adapter called Sangfor aTrust VNIC, which is used to keep the virtual network. It even blocked all IPv6 access of my Windows system by editing the registry. I think it had done much more to my computer that I hadn't found, which caused the problem I mentioned.

Thanks for reading my poor expression and I've tried to express everything clearly.

Screen capture of Wireshark:

[Screen Capture of Wireshark when I ping a domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEv56.png)

[Screen Capture of Wireshark when I traceroute 8.8.8.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzSHI.png)

[Screen Capture of Wireshark when I ping a domain, get a reply but not returned to WSL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkjCr.png)